# SoapUI: Use TestStep property on request

Tags: properties, soapui

I've got the following structure in SOAPUI:

- TestSuiteA

  - TestCaseA

    - TestStepA

      - Step A

TestStepA has property Operation. I would like to use on the request of StepA, the value of property Operation from TestStepA.

Thanks!

Comment: This does not make sense! You have 'TestCaseA' and 'TestStepA' at the same level - they are siblings. And what is 'StepA' under 'TestStepA'? SoapUI hierarchy does not go that deep.

Comment: There was an error on the indentation, now it's solved. A TestStep may have 1 or more steps.

Answer (score 2):

You can use standard [property expansion](http://www.soapui.org/Scripting-Properties/property-expansion.html): `${TestStepA#property_name}`.